Local DNS cache to file with TTL override?
A potential threat to internet connectivity is DNS servers are subjected to DDOS attacks.  To guard against this I would like to cache DNS records locally as I retrieve them in the course of each day's work, then serve them up even if expired if the DNS servers are unavailable. This would require storing the cache to file and not deleting records after TTL expires. Is this a good solution for the threat?  What's the easiest way to implement it: modified Pi-Hole?
